# What is the term for noddy code to test a principle

Tags: terminology

Apologies if this is a bad question for this forum!

A colleague thinks there is a short single-word term for a throwaway program written to verify that an algorithm or technique works as expected but can't remember what it is, and on-one else in the office has any idea.

Comment: This is actually a good question, since it is usually assumed in agile development, that everything gives at least a small incremental improvement for a user, but that is not always possible. IMHO great reference on that https://scaledagileframework.com/spikes/

Answer (score 1):

[Spike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spike_(software_development)) tends to be the term used in agile methodology to [describe](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/spike.html):

> A spike solution is a very simple program to explore potential
>   solutions. Build the spike to only addresses the problem under
>   examination and ignore all other concerns. Most spikes are not good
>   enough to keep, so expect to throw it away.

Some related terms might be

- [proof of concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept)
- [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product) (minimum viable product)